# How to clean out Blazor WebAssembly DLLs from browser?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I ran two sample Blazor WebAssembly apps accidentally on same port at https://localhost:44381, then things are messed up. One of the apps is erroring out because it tried and failed to load DLLs from the other sample app. I tried going to browser's devtool Application > Clear storage, but no help. How do I totally clean out the DLLs of a Blazor WebAssembly app from browser so that I could start fresh again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome and the new Edge press F12. This opens the developer tools. Whilst this is open right click the refresh page Icon on the browser. On that menu choose empty cache and hard refresh. This is the only way to clear everything including icons and PWA settings.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to do this, the other answer worked too though I'm not sure if it cleaned everything out. Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Comment: Neither of these options worked for me.  I was able to clear up the problem by publishing the app with the Delete Existing Files option to my local folder, then deleting all files in the deployed folder on the server and copying the newly published ones.

Comment: Thanks @BradIrby. I had a blazor app on my github pages and could load my new app with "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" but then I'd do a regular refresh and I'd get the blazor app back.

Comment: This answer doesn't clear out the cached DLL's, these need to be removed from the application cache as described in the other answer

Comment: This works, but its portents are troubling. Users can't be expected to do this. Do you know of a way to automate it?

Comment: @InteXX users should not need to do anything when your WASM application is updated. Updating your code will change the SHA256 hash in `blazor.boot.json`: see [a sample here](http://blazorchatsample.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.boot.json) as your application DLL has a new signature. The Blazor bootstrap JS in `blazor.webassembly.js` will fetch the new DLL and put it into the application cache. Any unchanged DLLs (eg. the framework libraries) will be reloaded from the cache.

Comment: @Quango — Thanks for the link and description. I'm slowly climbing this Blazor mountain, and every little hand up helps. The behavior you describe is what I'm seeing, except when the app throws an unhandled exception, as I discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/742815/how-does-blazor-know-which-controller-to-run.html). In that case, build/rebuilding the app had no effect; I couldn't get the updated code to load until I cleared the browser cache as described in this answer.

Comment: @Quango — Do you have any theory as to why the difference? Moreover, are you able to reproduce the scenario? After an unhandled exception, the browser (Brave, in my case, based on Chrome) won't load the updated WASM application without clearing the cache as described in this answer. Otherwise, though, the update occurs smoothly as you indicate. It's that exception that seems to be throwing things off.

Comment: @InteXX sorry, no idea. I just checked the `blazor.boot.json` file on [my sample app](http://blazorchatsample.azurewebsites.net/) - it isn't cached so it's reloaded each time the page is requested. If the app has been changed the sha256 hashes will be different, so it should load the new version. Check your boot file hasn't got any caching on it.. e.g. a proxy server?

Comment: @Quango — The implied fix is to not have an unhandled exception 

Answer (score 18):

Blazor WASM applications from version 3.1 download a file `blazor.boot.json` which lists the assemblies along with a sha256 hash to indicate the version. These assemblies are now downloaded to the browser's **Application Cache Storage** (see example below).

[image: DevTools showing Cache Storage area]

`Application -> Clear storage` should work - check that **Application cache** is selected on the `Application -> Clear storage` page:

[image: Chrome Clear Storage page]

Using the **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** will *not* clear out this cache, but will reload the `blazor.boot.json` file, and if the cached files have changed (the hash is different) then they should be reloaded.

You can also clear out individual assemblies from the Cache Storage view - right-click and you can delete them. When you refresh the application, Blazor will download the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

In your `.csproj` (for your wasm site) file you can force the app to download resources each time it's requested. Bit of a performance hit for the first load, but gets you over the current problem.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There are some caveats - see documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#disable-integrity-checking-for-non-pwa-apps-1

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks for posting this.  Works well with client-side offline files (served via a serviceworker) to avoid double caching.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> it cleans cache and gets files again.

Comment: For whatever reason this does not work all the time in dev. I have to do it multiple times for getting it to actually do the refresh :(